"invalid syntax" error while importing from lumibot
I am encountering an "invalid syntax" error while trying to import from Lumibot and I have no Idea how to fix. Tried Chatgpt for finding a solution but didn't work.
Here is my code:
from lumibot.brokers import Alpaca
from lumibot.strategies.strategy import Strategy
from lumibot.traders import Trader
from lumibot.backtesting import YahooDataBacktesting

and here is the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\trainvenv\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py:3505 in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)

  Cell In[27], line 1
    from lumibot.brokers import Alpaca

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\trainvenv\lib\site-packages\lumibot\brokers\__init__.py:5
    from .tradier import Tradier

  File ~\anaconda3\envs\trainvenv\lib\site-packages\lumibot\brokers\tradier.py:413
    match order.status.lower():
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


match-case was added in Python 3.10. If you use an older version it won't work.

but python 3.10 is incompatible with tensorflow 2.10, should create a separate env for working with  lumibot?

A separate environment is a good option if you don't need both libraries in the same program.

@Bardia, in that precise case, looking at the source code, the match/case statement is doing what and if/else statement could do. You could simply rewrite it with if and elif... Note that this is not particularly a good practice but would make your code actually work (unless there is another syntax error/versions mismatches)

@Lrx It's not their own code. Modifying third-party libraries like that is generally not recommended.

And this may not be the only Python version dependency, so trying to force these to work together opens a big can of worms.

@Barmar, You're right I'm just suggesting a quick workaround here

I tried python 3.12 and it worked thanks for your helps <3
